# Given are two structures $X$ and $Y$. Is $X$ isomorphic to $Y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $\sigma = \left\{f,R,S,c\right\}$ be a signature with a 1-digit function symbol $f$, a 2-digit relation symbol $R$, a 3-digit relation symbol $S$ and a constant symbol $c$.

Given are two $\sigma$-structures $X = (A, f^X, R^X,S^X,c^X), \space Y= (B, f^Y, R^Y, S^Y, c^Y)$ where

$A=\left\{q,r,s,t,u\right\}, \space\space R^X=\left\{(q,q),(r,t),(t,r),(u,q)\right\}, \space\space S^X=\left\{(q,s,q),(u,t,r)\right\}, \space\space c^X = s$

$B=\left\{1,2,3,4,5\right\}, \space R^Y = \left\{(5,5), (4,1), (2,5), (1,4)\right\}, \, S^Y = \left\{(2,1,4),(5,3,5)\right\}, \,\, c^Y= 3$

and the functions $f^X: A \rightarrow A, \space\space f^Y: B \rightarrow B$ defined by:

```
a∈A     | q  r  s  t  u               a∈B      | 1  2  3  4  5
-----------------------              --------------------------
f^X (a) | t  s  t  u  q               f^Y (a)   |2  5  1  3  1
```

Is $X$ isomorphic to $Y$?

---

I'm curious how this is solved correctly?

We have several different things given inside the structures.. So I think we need to do several different checks and all need to be satisfied.

So first of all we need to make sure that $A \rightarrow B$ is bijective.

From the defined functions we can see that they are bijective. $q \rightarrow 5, r \rightarrow 4, s \rightarrow 3, t \rightarrow 1, u \rightarrow 2$

---

Now we need to show that $R^X \Leftrightarrow R^Y$, I think. This is satisfied as well because let $q=5, u=2, r=4, t=1$. We see that we have same pairs if we insert and check.

---

We also need to make sure that all constant symbols $c$ are equal. This is satisfied as well $s=3$

---

Finally, all function symbols $f \in \sigma$ need to be equal. Well, they are but I cannot really say why :p

Thus $X$ is isomorphic to $Y$

Can you tell me if my attempt is correct and if not, how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be more or less on the right track.

You need to find a bijection $\eta : A\to B$ that preserves all the operations.  Since the constant symbols must be preserved ($\eta c^X = c^Y$), we must have

- $\eta(s) = 3$.

Next, since $(q,q)\in R^X$ and $(5,5)\in R^Y$ are the only pairs of the form $(x,x)$, we must have

- $\eta(q) = 5$,

for $\eta$ to preserve $R$. Looking a $S^X$ and $S^Y$ we see that $\eta$ must take $(q,s,q)$ to $(5,3,5)$, so $\eta$ must take $(u,t,r)$ to $(2,1,4)$ in order to have $\eta S^X = S^Y$:

- $\eta(u) = 2$
- $\eta(t) = 1$
- $\eta(r) = 4$

This completely defines $\eta$ on all of $A$, and $\eta$ is clearly a bijective mapping.  Now you just need to check that $f^Y\circ\eta = \eta\circ f^X$ by checking at each element of $\{q,r,s,t,u\}$, and verify that $\eta$ commutes with the rest  of $R$ and $S$ in the sense that $\eta R^X = R^Y$ and $\eta S^X = S^Y$, which is easy because of how we chose to define $\eta$.